# window.chrome property is false even for Chrome Browser

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, deployment

My application is deployed on windows server with expressjs(node) as backend and angular as frontend. Problem is that after building the project is production mode, when we run app using localhost it dont give error for browser but as I test the same app on Public IP it says Browser is not chrome even it is chrome snapshots attachment may help  you understand my question.
[On Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q69hQ.png)
[On Public IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw9uq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't just rely on `window.chrome` (opera sometimes gives false positives and as you've seen its not always guaranteed).

You might want to look at `navigator.userAgent` instead or `navigator.vendor`.